# Meteor third party async - "Meteor code must always run within a Fiber."

Tags: asynchronous, meteor, promise

I'm using stockfish npm package for a [collaborative chess game](http://chessmates.io/games):

It's written in a very non flexible way, and it seems I HAVE to use it like this:

```
Evaluator = (function() {
  var Promise = Meteor.npmRequire('promise');
  var ev = Meteor.npmRequire('stockfish')();
  var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var line;
    ev.onmessage = function(e) {
      if (e && typeof e === "object") {
          line = e.data;
      } else {
          line = e;
      }
      if (line.indexOf('Total Evaluation') > -1) {
        var score = parseFloat(line.split('Total Evaluation: ')[1].split('(')[0])
        resolve(score);
      }
    };
  });


  return function(movesStr) { 
    ev.postMessage('position startpos moves ' + movesStr);
    ev.postMessage("eval");
    return promise;
  }

})();
```

And to call it:

```
Meteor.methods({
  evaluate: evaluate
});

function evaluate(movesStr) {
  return Evaluator(movesStr);
}
```

So from my model, the call looks like that:

```
Meteor.call('evaluate', movesStr)
    .then(function(gameScore) {
      log('gameScore', gameScore);
      Games.update(
        { _id: gameId },
        { $set: { score: gameScore } },
        function(err, docs) {
          log('cacheGameScore', 'err', err)
        }
      );
    });
```

This code "works", I can see the result coming back accurately on the console.

however the DB call

```
Games.update
```

triggers this error:

```
[Error: Meteor code must always run within a Fiber. 
Try wrapping callbacks that you pass to non-Meteor 
libraries with Meteor.bindEnvironment.]
```

I've tried adding Meteor.wrapAsync and Meteor.bindEnvironment in many places, and I always get this error msg.

Any ideas of things to try here?

Comment: what's the call().then() syntax? Is that new?

Comment: That's a standard JS promise, implemented in npm

Comment: does it work without using promises? has this syntax worked for you in other examples?

Comment: what do u mean without using promises?

Comment: Meteor.call('evaluate', function (err, res) {Games.update()}); is the regular Meteor syntax

Comment: still getting the same err msg,  trying to play with your idea a bit

Comment: after 20 minutes of poking the code, still same error

Comment: I'd try do things even more the meteor way and then use wrapAsync. Look at the docs for the standard way to define a meteor method